# Add point button missing from CartoDB?

Tags: carto, point, editing

I'm trying to add a point to a map that already has points (table imported from a public source).  However I do not have the 'button' on the right hand side in my 'map view' to be able to add in my new point.  Any reason why this button might be absent?

I'm using CartoDB.

Comment: an screenshot of what you see would help, there should be a button on the bottom-left

Comment: it's on the bottom right!

Comment: If your table/visualization has a SQL applied or you're working with a synchronized table the button won't appear, as data is not editable in that status.

Answer (score 1):

When your visualization has a SQL query applied, which seems to be the case in this scenario, the table is set as "view mode", which means that you cannot edit the contents from that view.

Editing contents stands for editing the values in the cells of your table, but also for adding new points as it's the case.

In order to sort this out, you need to go to the original table (if you're working in a visualization) and add the points there. The changes in the table will be reflected in your visualization if your SQL query matches with the new data added.

Of course, clearing temporarily the SQL query is also another option. :-)

This behaviour and the suggestion to avoid this "blocking" mode is reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/152).